# How to train a simple linear regression model with SGD in pytorch successfully?

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent, pytorch

I was trying to train a simple polynomial linear regression model in pytorch with SGD. I wrote some self contained (what I thought would be extremely simple code), however, for some reason my model does not train as I thought it should.

I have 5 points sampled from a sine curve and try to fit it with a polynomial of degree 4. This is a convex problem so GD or SGD should find a solution with zero train error eventually as long as we have enough iterations and small enough step size. For some reason however my model does not train well (even though it seems that it is changing the parameters of the model. Anyone have an idea why? Here is the code (I tried making it self contained and minimal):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable

from maps import NamedDict

from plotting_utils import *

def index_batch(X,batch_indices,dtype):
    '''
    returns the batch indexed/sliced batch
    '''
    if len(X.shape) == 1: # i.e. dimension (M,) just a vector
        batch_xs = torch.FloatTensor(X[batch_indices]).type(dtype)
    else:
        batch_xs = torch.FloatTensor(X[batch_indices,:]).type(dtype)
    return batch_xs

def get_batch2(X,Y,M,dtype):
    '''
    get batch for pytorch model
    '''
    # TODO fix and make it nicer, there is pytorch forum question
    X,Y = X.data.numpy(), Y.data.numpy()
    N = len(Y)
    valid_indices = np.array( range(N) )
    batch_indices = np.random.choice(valid_indices,size=M,replace=False)
    batch_xs = index_batch(X,batch_indices,dtype)
    batch_ys = index_batch(Y,batch_indices,dtype)
    return Variable(batch_xs, requires_grad=False), Variable(batch_ys, requires_grad=False)

def get_sequential_lifted_mdl(nb_monomials,D_out, bias=False):
    return torch.nn.Sequential(torch.nn.Linear(nb_monomials,D_out,bias=bias))

def train_SGD(mdl, M,eta,nb_iter,logging_freq ,dtype, X_train,Y_train):
    ##
    N_train,_ = tuple( X_train.size() )
    #print(N_train)
    for i in range(nb_iter):
        # Forward pass: compute predicted Y using operations on Variables
        batch_xs, batch_ys = get_batch2(X_train,Y_train,M,dtype) # [M, D], [M, 1]
        ## FORWARD PASS
        y_pred = mdl.forward(batch_xs)
        ## LOSS + Regularization
        batch_loss = (1/M)*(y_pred - batch_ys).pow(2).sum()
        ## BACKARD PASS
        batch_loss.backward() # Use autograd to compute the backward pass. Now w will have gradients
        ## SGD update
        for W in mdl.parameters():
            delta = eta*W.grad.data
            W.data.copy_(W.data - delta)
        ## train stats
        if i % (nb_iter/10) == 0 or i == 0:
            current_train_loss = (1/N_train)*(mdl.forward(X_train) - Y_train).pow(2).sum().data.numpy()
            print('i = {}, current_loss = {}'.format(i, current_train_loss ) )
        ## Manually zero the gradients after updating weights
        mdl.zero_grad()
##
logging_freq = 100
dtype = torch.FloatTensor
## SGD params
M = 3
eta = 0.0002
nb_iter = 20*1000
##
lb,ub = 0,1
f_target = lambda x: np.sin(2*np.pi*x)
N_train = 5
X_train = np.linspace(lb,ub,N_train)
Y_train = f_target(X_train)
## degree of mdl
Degree_mdl = 4
## pseudo-inverse solution
c_pinv = np.polyfit( X_train, Y_train , Degree_mdl )[::-1]
## linear mdl to train with SGD
nb_terms = c_pinv.shape[0]
mdl_sgd = get_sequential_lifted_mdl(nb_monomials=nb_terms,D_out=1, bias=False)
## Make polynomial Kernel
poly_feat = PolynomialFeatures(degree=Degree_mdl)
Kern_train = poly_feat.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(N_train,1))
Kern_train_pt, Y_train_pt = Variable(torch.FloatTensor(Kern_train).type(dtype), requires_grad=False), Variable(torch.FloatTensor(Y_train).type(dtype), requires_grad=False)
train_SGD(mdl_sgd, M,eta,nb_iter,logging_freq ,dtype, Kern_train_pt,Y_train_pt)
```

the error seems to hover on 2ish:

```
i = 0, current_loss = [ 2.08996224]
i = 2000, current_loss = [ 2.03536892]
i = 4000, current_loss = [ 2.02014995]
i = 6000, current_loss = [ 2.01307297]
i = 8000, current_loss = [ 2.01300406]
i = 10000, current_loss = [ 2.01125693]
i = 12000, current_loss = [ 2.01162267]
i = 14000, current_loss = [ 2.01296973]
i = 16000, current_loss = [ 2.00951076]
i = 18000, current_loss = [ 2.00967121]
```

which is weird cuz it should be able to reach zero.

I also plotted the learned function:

[image]

the code for the plotting:

```
##
x_horizontal = np.linspace(lb,ub,1000).reshape(1000,1)
X_plot = poly_feat.fit_transform(x_horizontal)
X_plot_pytorch = Variable( torch.FloatTensor(X_plot), requires_grad=False)
##
fig1 = plt.figure()
#plots objs
p_sgd, = plt.plot(x_horizontal, [ float(f_val) for f_val in mdl_sgd.forward(X_plot_pytorch).data.numpy() ])
p_pinv, = plt.plot(x_horizontal, np.dot(X_plot,c_pinv))
p_data, = plt.plot(X_train,Y_train,'ro')
## legend
nb_terms = c_pinv.shape[0]
legend_mdl = f'SGD solution standard parametrization, number of monomials={nb_terms}, batch-size={M}, iterations={nb_iter}, step size={eta}'
plt.legend(
        [p_sgd,p_pinv,p_data],
        [legend_mdl,f'linear algebra soln, number of monomials={nb_terms}',f'data points = {N_train}']
    )
##
plt.xlabel('x'), plt.ylabel('f(x)')
plt.show()
```

---

I actually went ahead and implemented a TensorFlow version. That one does seem to train the model. I tried having both of them match by giving them the same initialization:

```
mdl_sgd[0].weight.data.fill_(0)
```

but that still didn't work. Tensorflow code:

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, nb_terms])
    Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])
    w = tf.Variable( tf.zeros([nb_terms,1]) )
    #w = tf.Variable( tf.truncated_normal([Degree_mdl,1],mean=0.0,stddev=1.0) )
    #w = tf.Variable( 1000*tf.ones([Degree_mdl,1]) )
    ##
    f = tf.matmul(X,w) # [N,1] = [N,D] x [D,1]
    #loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(Y - f))
    loss = tf.reduce_sum( tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(Y-f), 0))
    l2loss_tf = (1/N_train)*2*tf.nn.l2_loss(Y-f)
    ##
    learning_rate = eta
    #global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
    #learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(learning_rate=eta, global_step=global_step,decay_steps=nb_iter/2, decay_rate=1, staircase=True)
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(loss)
    with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
        Y_train = Y_train.reshape(N_train,1)
        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
        # Train
        for i in range(nb_iter):
            #if i % (nb_iter/10) == 0:
            if i % (nb_iter/10) == 0 or i == 0:
                current_loss = sess.run(fetches=loss, feed_dict={X: Kern_train, Y: Y_train})
                print(f'i = {i}, current_loss = {current_loss}')
            ## train
            batch_xs, batch_ys = get_batch(Kern_train,Y_train,M)
            sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={X: batch_xs, Y: batch_ys})
```

---

I also tried changing the initialization but it didn't change anything, which makes sense cuz it shouldn't make a big difference:

```
mdl_sgd[0].weight.data.normal_(mean=0,std=0.001)
```

---

Original post:

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-train-a-simple-linear-regression-model-with-sgd-in-pytorch-successfully/9620

---

This is how it should look like:

[image]

---

SOLUTION:

it seems that there is an issue with the result being returned as a vector instead of a number causing the issue. i.e. the following code fixed things:

```
    y_pred = model(batch_xs).view(-1) # change this to "y_pred = model(batch_xs)" to get the incorrect results
    loss = (y_pred - batch_ys).pow(2).mean()
```

which seems completely mysterious to me. Does someone know why this fixed the issue? it just seems like magic.

Comment: What behavior you are expecting and what you are getting, please explain them precisely.

Comment: @WasiAhmad sorry if I didn't make it clear. But I expect the training to converge to a sensible solution (like the linear algebra solution). In fact, I did say in the question that I implemented it in TensorFlow and that it worked **exactly** the way I expected it. Which makes me think there must be something wrong with my Pytorch code. So in short. Why does the tensorflow code work and pytorch does not?

Comment: why aren't you using pytorch built-in optimizer (torch.optim.SGD())?

Comment: @Maximilian because I just copy pasted that line of code from a tutorial: http://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/pytorch_with_examples.html#autograd and I didn't really even consider that such simple code would change anything. I also don't know if pytorch changed or the tutorial changed in between when I made it and when pytorch 0.2.0 was released... Furthermore, this is just a toy example, I don't intend to use SGD necessarily later on so I thought it was important to be able to do most of these things more directly and an example that I do know the answer to.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is really subtle but essentially it's because pytorch is using numpy broadcasting rules. So when a column vector `(3,1)` and an array (i.e. dim is `(3,)` ) then what happens is that broadcasting produces a `(3,3)` matrix (note this wouldn't happen when you subtract a row vector `(1,3)` vector with a `(3,)` array, I guess arrays are treated as row vectors). This is really bad because it means that we compute the matrix of all pairwise differences between every label and every prediction. Of course this is nonsensical and produces a bug because we don't want the prediction of the first label point to match the prediction of every other label in the data set. Of course that won't produce anything sensible.

So it seems the answer is just to avoid wrong numpy broadcasting by either reshaping things during training or before the data is fed. Either one should work.

---

To avoid the error one can attach use this code:

```
def check_vectors_have_same_dimensions(Y,Y_):
    '''
    Checks that vector Y and Y_ have the same dimensions. If they don't
    then there might be an error that could be caused due to wrong broadcasting.
    '''
    DY = tuple( Y.size() )
    DY_ = tuple( Y_.size() )
    if len(DY) != len(DY_):
        return True
    for i in range(len(DY)):
        if DY[i] != DY_[i]:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: yes, you should always use `view` or `expand_as` or the likes to make sure the variable shape are really what you expect.

Comment: @jdhao I think my issue was that I wasn't even aware at all that it could even lead to problems. I think the unspoken assumption I had was that if shapes don't match in some way an error would be thrown so I'd find out anyway. That assumptions seems to be wrong clearly. Thanks!

Comment: the [new broadcasting rule](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/broadcasting.html) was introduced in torch 0.2.0, some of the method behaves differently from previous version. Some of the method such as [`sum()`](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.sum) will produce different output depending on whether you use `keepdim=True`.